# Reason Ruby and RoR projects tend to use Sass rather than LESS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, less

I'm starting my first RoR project, and I've been a LESS user for a while now. I have nothing against Sass, I just stumbled on LESS first. That said:

1. I've found significantly more references to using Sass with Compass rather than LESS with SimpLESS
2. On first glance, the Ruby Mine IDE (which I'm considering trying out) seems to have a Sass option built in, but nothing for LESS.

I don't want to know which of Sass and LESS is "better", simply if there is an inherent reason to prefer Sass with Ruby development.

Comment: Umm, because it's the default in Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, it's a question of taste. Both languages have similar concepts (variables, mixins, nesting, ...) and thus can be used similarly.

I personally prefer the SCSS flavor or SASS because it mostly resembles CSS (in fact, it is syntactically CSS) and I don't have to fully learn a new language. To me it feels very naturally. LESS (and to a certain amount SASS) on the other hand uses a new syntax which makes it harder to start using and doesn't allow to use existing CSS unchanged (which is a huge point for me).

Another important point is that Rails since 3.1 endorses SASS as the default stylesheet library. While you can override this and use whatever you like, many people use what comes as the default.

Comment: Good answer - web development is a complex subject, especially if you ignore the default choices that most frameworks make for you!

Answer (score 0):

SASS resembles with HAML that's why I prefer SASS